# Left join with subquery on parent table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temp table (#c) with some columns. One of this columns contains the name of the client and I just have that to do a search (no id's or something useful). In order to get more information from the client, I have a table with person data.

The following query is incomplete, but the main idea is there. What is wrong?

```
select *
from #c c
left join (
    select
        case
            when LEN(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))))-LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))), ' ', '')) = 1 then 0
            when LEN(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))))-LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))), ' ', '')) = 2 then 1
            when LEN(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))))-LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))), ' ', '')) >= 3 then
                select @varA1 = SUBSTRING(c.Client, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', c.Client + ' ')-1)
                select @varN = SUBSTRING(c.Client, CHARINDEX(' ', c.Client + ' ')+1, LEN(c.Client))
                select @varA2 = SUBSTRING(@varN, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @varN + ' ')-1)
                select @varN = SUBSTRING(@varN, CHARINDEX(' ', @varN + ' ')+1, LEN(@varN))

                select top 1 UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.txt_a1)) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(m.txt_a2)) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(m.txt_name))) as FClient, m.txt_sex, tc.txt_desc as 'Status'
                from person m
                inner join test tc on m.cod_est = tc.cod_est
                where UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.txt_a1))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@varA1))) and UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.txt_a2))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@varA2))) and UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.txt_name))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@varN)))
        end
) x
on UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))) like '%' + x.FClient + '%'
```

PD: I put a top 1 condition due my table of persons has duplicated records. Sometimes the records in temp table won't exists in person table.

Here's an example to guide you:
[image]

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) also check [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: WHat makes you think it is wrong? In other words what is is about the results that you don't like or what error are you getting?

Comment: Your 3rd `when` looks odd.  It must return a single value, but it contains multiple `select` statements with variable assignments.

Comment: Your query doesn't make any sense at all.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help other people help you.

Comment: CASE is an expression. It is used to return a value for a single column. It is not used to control logical flow.  You can't just arbitrarily assign variables and such like this in the middle of a query. There is just so much wrong from how a query works I can't begin to unravel this.

Comment: I have add and example

Comment: Can you post some actual data instead of a picture? And the desired output.

Comment: I have restrictions to sharing information. So, the picture has real data (for one client). Of course, person table has millions of records, as well as temp table, has thousands of record. I know the 3rd CASE statement is completely wrong, I'm just trying to let you know that I have 1 single column with a full name and different fields in another table. The idea of variables is to compare and to know if exists client to get the available data.

Comment: The data doesn't have to be real, in fact it should be fake data. The point is that I do not want to spend 30 minutes putting together tables and insert statements from your picture so I can then work on the query that you need help with. And of course the query you posted is pulling from a temp table, you posted 3 tables. You have to put in some of the work in order to get free help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, fellas, for your support. I saw and corrected the mistakes. I understand your point, Sean Lange, all comments were very useful.

I rewrote the query as follows and it's working. I think it is very slow. Do you recommend an index or something to improve the time? Regards

```
select *
from #c c
left join (
    select c1.[ID Incident], c1.[Paid to], c1.Client,
        case
            --when LEN(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))))-LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))), ' ', '')) = 1 then ''
            --when LEN(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))))-LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))), ' ', '')) = 2 then ''
            when LEN(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c1.Client))))-LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c1.Client))), ' ', '')) >= 3 then
                (
                    select top 1 UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.txt_a1)) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(m.txt_a2)) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(m.txt_name))) as Client
                    from mpersona m
                    where UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.txt_a1))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(c1.Client, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')-1)))) and UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.txt_a2))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(c1.Client, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')+1, LEN(c1.Client)), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(c1.Client, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')+1, LEN(c1.Client)) + ' ')-1)))) and UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.txt_name))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(c1.Client, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')+1, LEN(c1.Client)), CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(c1.Client, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')+1, LEN(c1.Client)) + ' ')+1, LEN(SUBSTRING(c1.Client, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')+1, LEN(c1.Client)))))))
                )
        end as 'Client',
        case
            --when LEN(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))))-LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))), ' ', '')) = 1 then ''
            --when LEN(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))))-LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))), ' ', '')) = 2 then ''
            when LEN(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c1.Client))))-LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c1.Client))), ' ', '')) >= 3 then
                (
                    select top 1 m.date_birth
                    from mpersona m
                    where UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.txt_a1))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(c1.Client, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')-1)))) and UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.txt_a2))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(c1.Client, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')+1, LEN(c1.Client)), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(c1.Client, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')+1, LEN(c1.Client)) + ' ')-1)))) and UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.txt_name))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(c1.Client, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')+1, LEN(c1.Client)), CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(c1.Client, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')+1, LEN(c1.Client)) + ' ')+1, LEN(SUBSTRING(c1.Client, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')+1, LEN(c1.Client)))))))
                )
        end as 'date_birth',
        case
            --when LEN(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))))-LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))), ' ', '')) = 1 then ''
            --when LEN(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))))-LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))), ' ', '')) = 2 then ''
            when LEN(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c1.Client))))-LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c1.Client))), ' ', '')) >= 3 then
                (
                    select top 1 m.txt_sex
                    from mpersona m
                    where UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.txt_a1))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(c1.Client, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')-1)))) and UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.txt_a2))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(c1.Client, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')+1, LEN(c1.Client)), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(c1.Client, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')+1, LEN(c1.Client)) + ' ')-1)))) and UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.txt_name))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(c1.Client, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')+1, LEN(c1.Client)), CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(c1.Client, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')+1, LEN(c1.Client)) + ' ')+1, LEN(SUBSTRING(c1.Client, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')+1, LEN(c1.Client)))))))
                )
        end as 'txt_sex',
        case
            --when LEN(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))))-LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))), ' ', '')) = 1 then ''
            --when LEN(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))))-LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Client))), ' ', '')) = 2 then ''
            when LEN(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c1.Client))))-LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(c1.Client))), ' ', '')) >= 3 then
                (
                    select top 1 tc.txt_desc as 'State'
                    from mpersona m
                    inner join test_civil tc on m.cod_est_civil = tc.cod_est_civil
                    where UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.txt_a1))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(c1.Client, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')-1)))) and UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.txt_a2))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(c1.Client, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')+1, LEN(c1.Client)), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(c1.Client, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')+1, LEN(c1.Client)) + ' ')-1)))) and UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.txt_name))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(c1.Client, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')+1, LEN(c1.Client)), CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(c1.Client, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')+1, LEN(c1.Client)) + ' ')+1, LEN(SUBSTRING(c1.Client, CHARINDEX(' ', c1.Client + ' ')+1, LEN(c1.Client)))))))
                )
        end as 'State'
    from #c c1
) x
on c.[ID Incident] = x.[ID Incident] and c.[Paid to] = x.[Paid to] and c.Client = x.Client
```